# asp.net webform default routing does not work

Tags: asp.net, url, routes

EDIT: I solved by myself.Cause the stylesheet reference path is `/css/style.css` not `css/style.css`,url will not be fixed by asp.net.I found that `<link>` `<meta>` and `<title>` will add as an server control to head when head tagged with `runat="server"`,So these server control will auto fix current reference problem.

!!!BUT,`<script>` is ignored,One of the solutions is `<%= ResolveClientUrl('~/js/jquery.js') %>`.But It does not work when you have a theme attched to master page,asp.net canot add stylesheets in App_Themes to head when it contains such `<% %>` expression,asp.net will throw an exception.

So it seems like the best solution is using `<ScriptManager>`.

Another important discover is that when you have a `<ContentPlaceHolder>` in master `runat=server` head,stylesheet inside `<Content>` of child page using this master page will not be treat as a server control.So in `<Content>` of child page you must use `<%= ResolveClientUrl%>` to handle url fix.

ORINGIAL:

I'm running asp.net 4.0 on IIS 7 Express.  I route "MarketList/{type}" to "~/MarketList.aspx" with default value `new {type = 0}`.  The URL "localhost:4888/MarketList" just works well, I can recieve default value "0".

But I found that the "/" will mess up the stylesheet and javascript references defined in "Main.master" master page.  "Main.master" is in the root level with "MarketList.aspx".  The stylesheet in "Main.master" is defined as `css/style.css`.  The "css" folder is also at the root level.  When I'm accessing by "/MarketList", it works well.  But, "/MarketList/1" gives the value "1" to `{type}`.  The URL of the stylesheet in the page becomes "../css/style.css" which points to "/MarketList/css/style.css".  This doesn't exists (obviously).

So, I decide to use "-" to split those parts, I route "market-list-{type}" with same setting just like above.  But, I found I can not access the default routing URL which I thought would be "localhost:4888/market-list-".  "localhost:4888/market-list" does not work either.  Only "/market-list-0" will work.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Take a look at Phil Haack's Route Debugger tool:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx  And for your content links breaking, write them like <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/...css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/...js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  Then the links won't break anymore across different views.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,But I'm only use asp.net routing in webform,not in asp.net mvc.@asawyer

Comment: Oh, sorry. I seen routing and asp and assume mvc.